# Is there any way to run MobileFirst Platform Foundation Docker (IBM Containers) images on a local Docker instance?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

I followed the below steps and created the image of MobileFirst Platform Foundation:

[Run IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation on IBM Containers](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/bluemix/run-foundation-on-bluemix/)

The above steps push the image to Bluemix and start it. But I'd like to use the image on my docker-machine, especially for trouble shooting (ic/ice commands are limited compared to docker commands, and sometimes I can not access IBM container by ssh).

But the mobilefirst foundation image uses bluemix database service so perhaps we need to some environment variables like VCAP?

Comment: If it is starter container, it seems that we can. "Running ibm-mobilefirst-starter container locally" https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/10/25/running-ibm-mobilefirst-starter-container-locally/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your image uses Bluemix service database, I'm not what you can do. Perhaps you should switch to a local database for the during of the local image run.

Last time this was attempted, the following were the steps taken:

1. Run `docker images` to list the available images in the repository and their ID, tag, etc...
2. To start your image on a local container run: `docker run -d -p 9080:9080 -p 9443:9443 <image ID>`
3. To verify that the image is properly configured and the MobileFirst project runtime is available, launch the MobileFirst Console by loading the following URL: `http://192.168.59.103:9080/worklightconsole`

Again, these commands may differ. Hopefully it'll work in your case.